# Removing the values from array by comparing substr value

Tags: angularjs

I have list of roles in an array `$scope.role = [];` I need to show the selected role in chip form with first 3 characters . So I used `substr(0,3)` in `$scope.multiRoles` where I am pushing my selected roles.My problem is when I am deleting the role , I am checking out the index and pushing the data back to `$scope.role` where the substring is pushed but not the original one.For example Doc is pushed instead of Doctor

```
  $scope.role.push("Doctor","Engineer","Lawyer","Designer");
```

Add Role :

```
    $scope.AddRole = function(index){
    if($scope.model.role !== undefined ){
   $scope.multiRoles.push($scope.model.role.substr(0,3));
    var index = $scope.role.indexOf($scope.model.role); 
     $scope.role.splice(index,1);
           }}
```

Remove Role:

```
        $scope.removeRoles = function(index,data){
            if(($scope.multiRoles!== null ) && ($scope.multiRoles.length>1)) 
            var index = $scope.multiRoles.indexOf(data);
          $scope.multiRoles.splice(index,1);
         $scope.role.push(data);
                       };
```

HTML:

```
<span class="file-tag-baloon1" alue ="data"  
  ng-repeat="role in filteredRoles track by $index" >
    <span>{{role}}</span>
  <a ng-click="removeRoles($index,role)"class="remove1">X</a> 
</span>
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that when you delete role from `$scope.role` you lose information about this role hence you can't recover it. As a solution you can store full names of roles in both arrays and use substring for representation only in your html like `{{multiRole.substr(0, 3)}}`, so you will have two arrays with data that can go both ways without any losses.